# Generate dates between 2 ranges (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, range

I'm newbie in javascript and need a little help.

How to generate all dates between dateA to dateB.

For example:

```
dateA = 07/01/2013
dateB = 07/01/2014
```

Wanted result:

```
07/01/2013, 07/02/2013, 07/03/2013, 07/04/2013...and so on
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple javascript date math... not really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356164/simple-javascript-date-math-not-really)

Comment: You can try using momentjs.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have the simplest library for dealing with dates.  Particularly when it comes to adding dates.  One common method is to convert the date object into its representation in seconds using getTime() then to add the required number of seconds and pass that result into the new Date method.  Something like this:

```
var dateA = new Date(2014,6,1,0,0,0);
var dateB = new Date(2014,6,4,0,0,0);
for(var myDate = dateA; myDate <= dateB; myDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
{
    var formatedDate = myDate.getMonth()+1;
    formatedDate += "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
    console.log(formatedDate);
}
```

Also remember that in javascript months are zero indexed (0-11).